# kmeans on fisherIris data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, k-means

I have the following script for kmeans in Matlab:

```
load fisheriris
k = 3; 
clusterIndex = kmeans(meas,3);
scatter(meas(:,1),meas(:,2),[],clusterIndex, 'filled')
```

How to plot the centroids of each group? 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html):

> [IDX,C] = kmeans(X,k) returns the k cluster centroid locations in the
>   k-by-p matrix C

So in your case simply do this:

```
[clusterIndex, centroids] = kmeans(meas,3);
```

By the way you might like [`gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html), it will colour your clusters nicely for you.

Comment: Can you please give me the plot script how to show these centroids

Comment: @user19565 That is literally in the link I posted. Just read down. `plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'kx','MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)`

Comment: Thank you again for your support! the only problem is that I have error when running the program:

Comment: The error is as follows:Error using prdataset/plot (line 6)
Use for displaying datasets SCATTERD or SHOW

Error in Kmeans (line 6)
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'kx','MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)  what can be problem?

Comment: You have overloaded the `plot` function with your own `plot` function in the `prdataset` folder... consider renaming that function to not hide Matab's own `plot`